# Should Good Content Strategy Possibly Create Multiple Domains?

Tags: content, multiple-domains

[See the notes below about duplicate questions.]  We have a friend whose site sells different types of things-- rare coins, jewelry, fine art, antiques, etc.  For SEO reasons (creating a high-quality information site about each market/topic), we were wondering if it was better to keep this all together as one site, with a somethingcoins.com type URL (and so jewelry would be somethingcoins.com/jewelry), or whether we should create a separate somethingjewelry.com and target that whole site on jewelry products and related information, to be an authority in that one jewelry market.

So I guess the question is, for Google rankings, is it better to have multiple small sites which are each focused on a single topic/market?  Will this lead to higher authority for the site?  Or should we continue to group them all (like somethingcoins.com/jewelry) and trust that the aggregate number of inbound links and overall site authority will be better this way?  It also seems more difficult for somethingcoins.com/jewelry to compete against other sites that are targeted/focused on jewelry only (or am I maybe wrong about that?).

RE: DUPLICATE QUESTIONS. I know there are other questions here about multiple domains, but those seem to be asking how to redirect multiple top-level domains into a single site, or to show a single site's content on multiple top-level domains, possibly in different languages, but all assuming that the site content itself makes sense as one collection of pages. Our question here is different--- mostly asking if their current collection of coins, jewelry, art, etc, makes sense to group together on a single site if we're trying to create an authority site for each of those markets.  Thanks so much for your feedback and ideas.

UPDATE #1 re: DUPLICATE QUESTIONS. I should clarify that I'm not suggesting multiple domains like buygoldjewelry.com, buycheapjewelry.com, etc. which is the focus of the linked "Duplicate" question above.  I agree with the advice on that question, that Google wants you to build a brand.  But aren't BrandCoins.com and BrandJewelry.com two completely separate sites, target audiences, and markets?  Each can be a solid information site for the particular market, since they are very different (rare coins vs. fine art, for example).  Or more importantly, doesn't combining these all to just Brand.com/coins and Brand.com/jewelry actually LOWER the authority of the overall site in each category, when it competes against other sites focused on ONLY jewelry, for example?

Comment: @johnconde -- I've added more information to hopefully address this being marked as duplicate. In this case, these aren't SEO-driven minor domain variations, but completely different markets. Won't a combined site have more difficulty competing against a focused somethingjewelry.com competitor?

Comment: Rather than add updates explaining how the question is different from question marked duplicate, edit the original question to clarify the difference. Also, consider limiting it to one definable question that can be answered concretely and specifically.